# Remove language prefix from base URL

Tags: i18n-l10n

I've installed the Internationalization module in order to make a multilingual site, I've set italian as default language, but there's a problem, the front page is always in english. I've checked the base URL and I've noticed that there's a language prefix, is it possible remove?
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply neok! I've searched several hours before asking, anyway I've figured out: on  Admin > Configuration > Regional and language > Languages, on the Language Switcher tab Content selection mode needs to be checked on "Selected languages from language block." Have a nice day you too!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I think people do not know how to use [search](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=drupal%20internationalization%20base%20page&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) in our time.
You can find the answer on `stackoverflow`, [similar question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168289/multiple-frontpages-in-mutiple-languages). Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're mixing a few things here, and I also think that the comment in the question (which should actually have been posted as an answer ...), is only like a partial fix or workaround. What, IMHO; the real issue seems to be here, is that the URL of the homepage has not been defined as a "multilingual" variable, as further explained below.

The relative URL to display as the front page is specified within admin/config/system/site-information . If you want to be able to specify a value for it that is different for each of the site's languages, make sure you have made it a "multilingual" variable (it should say "This is a multilingual variable.") in the description of that variable on that page.

For more details about how to get this done, refer to my answer to [How to make content translation available for front page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158537/content-translation-front-page-not-avaible/158591#158591).